# How can I do a Func<object[],Expression<Func<T,bool>>> dynamic?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I am working on doing a .Find(objects[] keys) method that dynamically creates an lambda function to query a database.

Basically what I want is:

```
var mykeys = new Guid("37ec1659-b35e-46c9-a7fc-e9802644ca1a");
IQueryable<T> database ;
Func<object[],Expression<Func<T,bool>>> objectFinder = CreateKeyExpression(typeof(T));
var foundObject = database.FirstOrDefault(objectFinder(mykeys));
```

and

```
private LambdaExpression CreateKeyExpression(Type C1Type)
{

    ParameterExpression instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(C1Type);
    ParameterExpression keyParameters = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]));

    PropertyInfo[] objectKeys = C1Type.GetKeyProperties().ToArray();
    var expr = Expression.Equal( Expression.TypeAs( Expression.Property(instanceParameter,objectKeys[0]),typeof(object)),
      Expression.ArrayIndex(keyParameters,Expression.Constant(0))); 


    for (int i = 1; i < objectKeys.Length; i++)
    {
        expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(instanceParameter,objectKeys[i]),
            Expression.ArrayIndex(keyParameters,Expression.Constant(i))
            )); 

    }

    var lmp= Expression.Lambda(expr, instanceParameter);

    return Expression.Lambda(lmp, keyParameters);
}
```

Any ideas of how I can achieve this? The above gives me a `Func<object[],Func<T,bool>>`, which makes the IQueryable to a IEnumerable, meaning it won't do it on the database end.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `Expression.Constant` method instead of the `Expression.ArrayIndex`, because you will not be able to pass to your expression array with the key values ​​using the `FirstOrDefault` method.

```
private static LambdaExpression CreateKeyExpression(Type C1Type, object[] parameters)
{
    var instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(C1Type);
    PropertyInfo[] objectKeys = C1Type.GetKeyProperties().ToArray();

    var expr = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(instanceParameter, objectKeys[0]),
        Expression.Constant(parameters[0], objectKeys[0].PropertyType));


    for (int i = 1; i < objectKeys.Length; i++)
    {
        expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(instanceParameter, objectKeys[i]),
            Expression.Constant(parameters[i], objectKeys[i].PropertyType)));
    }
    return Expression.Lambda(expr, instanceParameter);
}

var parameters = new object[] { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };
var lambdaExpression = CreateKeyExpression(typeof(TestClass), parameters);
var testClasses = new List<TestClass>() { new TestClass { Id = (Guid)parameters[0], Id1 = (Guid)parameters[1] } };
var testClass = testClasses.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault((Expression<Func<TestClass, bool>>)lambdaExpression);
```

Comment: Interesting, i solved it a bit differently. Putting object[] parameters in the CreateKeyExpression was not an option. I wanted to be able to cache the the expression for a given C1Type as why i asked for a Func<Object[],Expression<Func<T,bool>>. Which would let me cache it for every type and not generate it everytime a new set of keys are used. I will post my solution also just if others want it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
private Expression<Func<object[], Expression<Func<C1Source, bool>>>> CreateKeyExpression<C1Source>()
{

    ParameterExpression instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(C1Source));
    ParameterExpression keyParameters = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]));

    PropertyInfo[] objectKeys = typeof(C1Source).GetKeyProperties().ToArray();
    var expr = Expression.Equal( Expression.Property(instanceParameter,objectKeys[0]),
     Expression.Convert( 
        Expression.ArrayIndex(keyParameters,Expression.Constant(0)),
        objectKeys[0].PropertyType)
        ); 

    for (int i = 1; i < objectKeys.Length; i++)
    {
        expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, Expression.Equal(
            Expression.Property(instanceParameter,objectKeys[i]),
            Expression.Convert(
                Expression.ArrayIndex(keyParameters,Expression.Constant(i)),
                objectKeys[i].PropertyType)
                ); 

    }

    var lmp= Expression.Lambda(expr, instanceParameter);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], Expression<Func<C1Source, bool>>>>(lmp, keyParameters);

}
```